# Detox: best way to send parameters to app

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I implemented Detox for e2e tests in my react-native application, I have 2 tests:

1. Launch -> Not logged -> display login form -> Main screen
2. Launch -> Logged -> Main screen

auth informations are stored with AsyncStorage, I implemented a mockup store.e2e.js using Repackager. Fine, but I need to start app with two different sets of data storage: one empty for test1 and another with username/password for test2.

So I add a hack with `launchApp` + url parameter or `device.sendUrl`, catched by Store mock at init using `Linking.addEventListener('url', callback)`. Ok problem solved. But it forced me to activate deeplinking on Android and iOS, which I don't want in my app... Made a special case in the code only for testing, it is bad.

I understand it is a well known problem, and repackager was made for that:
https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/91

But how to inject some parameters in app at launch for specific tests, is it possible ? What is your best practice for such problem ?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you can send launch argument to your process, which you can query during runtime. You can also create a mock file for your JS, where, instead of replacing your logic, you just set some variable to hold the value you want to pass, and then load your normal logic.